# Regexp to find patterns which starts with, contains and end with specific words (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a regexp to get urls in img src attribute :

```
$string = 'Ut quo totam aperiam possimus recusandae
<img src="mylink.jpg"/>
Bo nostrum vero distinctio eligendi.
<img src="mylinktmpfileandsomeotherstuff.jpg"/>
<img src="myotherlink.jpg"/>
Lorem ipsum';

preg_match_all('/(?<=src=").+?(?=")/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Which is giving :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'mylink.jpg' (length=10)
      1 => string 'mylinktmpfileandsomeotherstuff.jpg' (length=34)
      2 => string 'myotherlink.jpg' (length=15)
```

https://regex101.com/r/UA3lVf/1

How can I filter my search to only get urls who contains the word "tmpfile" in it ?

So I would get :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'mylinktmpfileandsomeotherstuff.jpg' (length=34)
```

Comment: `.*tmpfile.*` instead of `.+?`?

Comment: Final solution is /(?<=src=").*tmpfile.*?(?=")/
I added ? after .*tmpfile.* to stop at first occurence of "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex to get the src of an image that contains `tmpfile`.

You can use an xpath query, with DomDocument and DOMXpath.

```
//img[contains(@src, 'tmpfile')]
```

For example:

```
$string = 'Ut quo totam aperiam possimus recusandae
<img src="mylink.jpg"/>
Bo nostrum vero distinctio eligendi.
<img src="mylinktmpfileandsomeotherstuff.jpg"/>
<img src="myotherlink.jpg"/>
Lorem ipsum';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query("//img[contains(@src, 'tmpfile')]") as $elm) {
    echo $elm->getAttribute("src") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
mylinktmpfileandsomeotherstuff.jpg
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/cRnSY)